# How to break from while loop with active thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, lambda, break

I know that's not the best way to word my question.  In my server, some of issues BASICALLY comes down to this -
How do you break from the while loop once conditionA is met?  And is it possible to destroy a specific threads if conditionB is met?

Unfortunately the main thread is blocked by the recvfrom() function forever unless I can break from the loop.

```
while (1)
{
  recBytes = recvfrom(sock, packetBuff, 8, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &SockLength);

  std::thread TX([&] 
  {
    //process packet task

    if(conditionA == 1)
      break from while loop

    if(conditionB == 1)
      destroy any active threads spawned by TX

    .
    .
    .
    much more tasks

  });

  TX.detach();
} 

.
.
.
continue rest of code
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using some asio library? boost.asio comes to mind, but there are other libraries available as well. Even though in the case as stated, closing the socket from another thread is simple and effective enough to exit from recv_from, and checking for the error case, as I hope you already do.  A break statement will exit the loop.

Comment: May I suggest this lecture on YT: "History of Time: Asynchronous C++ - Steven Simpson"?  It's well worth the time before designing a client/server app using modern c++ techniques.  Whatever the desired size of you app.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Do you mind showing me in code what this would look like please?

Comment: Do check the boost.asio code samples: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp.   Note that the server can handle many clients while running on a single thread.   Code from the presentation above: https://github.com/stevejims/acpp.  Some of this code can handle 50+k simultaneous requests while running on a single thread, which is always interesting.

Comment: Why would you want to exit from the loop?  That would effectively kill your daemon.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to break from a blocking I/O call is replacing it with select()/poll()/etc that waits on 2 sockets: your data socket and a non-blocking notification pipe. If select() reports you can read or write to your data socket, you do just that, in a non-blocking fashion. If it reports data is available on the notification pipe, you break from the loop. Any thread can write a single byte to the non-blocking notification pipe to cause select() in another thread to return.

As for destroying other threads, you can't do that without cooperation from those threads. Basically, you need a way to notify them that they need to quit. If those threads don't do blocking calls, then a simple atomic flag with periodic checks will do. Otherwise, you need a way to break from a blocking call. If it's an I/O call, introduce another notification pipe. If it's blocking on a condition variable, use std::condition_variable::notify_all().

Comment: Do check the boost.asio code samples: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp

Comment: @Tulon Do you mind showing me in code what this would look like please? I cant use third party libraries

Comment: @djent I explained how it's done in principle, but implementing it is up to you.